# Are YouTube creators using "enjoy" in a new intransitive sense?

Tags: verbs, intransitive-verbs, sociolinguistics

Many YouTube creators end their videos with a statement  similar to

> If you enjoyed, please remember to click the thumbs-up button!

Invariably, there is no explicit direct object for the verb "enjoy". This is something I've only ever encountered in YouTube videos.

Language websites such as [this one](https://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=1592) say that "enjoy" is an obligatory transitive verb, meaning it requires a direct object.

You could of course say there's an implied direct object "the video", but this seems to me like some new sociolect construct, where the direct object becomes irrelevant because of immersion in the subject matter.

Has this been recognized or studied by anyone? If so, have they traced the origin to YouTube, or did creators bring it from some other medium?
Of course the imperative "[Enjoy](http://movies2.nytimes.com/library/magazine/home/20001022mag-onlanguage.html)!" has been around for a while, but for the purpose of this question, you'd have to trace its evolution into YouTube or whatever medium preceded that.

---

Reminder: This is NOT about the imperative "Enjoy!".  This is about the conditional use and where it originated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Enjoy!" Enjoy what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202321/enjoy-enjoy-what)

Comment: It's something out of the Elision Fields.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has in the entry for **enjoy**:

> 

OED mentiuons that "Enjoy!" is not intransitive:

> Draft additions March 2003

> [In later use, probably after dialectal Yiddish genist.] In imperative, **with ellipsis of object**: take pleasure in the thing (frequently food or drink) being presented.

> 1876   H. James Roderick Hudson ix. 304   *Don't mind the pain, and it will cease to trouble you. Enjoy, enjoy; it is your duty.*

> 1959   H. Golden For 2¢ Plain ii. 92   *When my mother served our meals..she would always say, ‘Enjoy, enjoy’... The word ‘enjoy’ was seldom used by itself. It was always repeated.*

> 1998   30 All Time Great Recipes (BBC Good Food) Autumn 1/1   *We hope that in this selection, you will rediscover some old friends—and make some new ones as well. Enjoy!*

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the intransitive usage is older than You Tubers:

> [Enjoy!](https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/verbs-in-learners-dictionaries-part-1) mouthed by tired waiters as they abandon you to your meal. In Macmillan Dictionary this is recorded as a *sub-sense (1a),*  although traditional ELT websites still inform us sternly that ‘enjoy always has an object’.

***[Enjoy:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enjoy)***

> *(Intransitive always in imperative ​spoken)* -used for saying that you hope someone enjoys something that they are about to do.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Comment: I did specify that the imperative use was different.

Comment: @Spencer - it is clearly derived from the above older usage.

Comment: Then please edit your answer to explain that. "Clearly" is used to gloss important concepts over far too often.

Comment: How did this happen? It isn’t clear to me.

Comment: @Spencer *I did specify that the imperative use was different.* I know, but it isn't - the object is still ellipsed.

Comment: @Greybeard You've suggested a different explanation from user121863's. So you should post an answer.